# How to add calculation results to another dataset based on a filter

Tags: r, dataset

I have two datasets and I need to add a value that is based on specific levels of the two variables' values.I need to add to `dat dataset` the value that is calculated on the `dat1 dataset` so the output should be like in `dat2`.Any idea how to this ( the values in dat1 are text)?

```
 dat3 <- read.table(text = "      lamps  vases
                                  7  9
                                  1  6 
                                  3  5 
                                  7  8 
                                  5  4
                                  1  3 
                                  0  7
                                  6  6
                                  8  9  ", header = TRUE) 

dat2 <- read.table(text = "      lamps  vases est
                                  3,5   4,5    0.6
                                  8      9      0.4
                   ", header = TRUE) 
dat2 <- read.table(text = "      lamps  vases est
                                   7  9       0
                                   1  6       0
                                   3  5       0.6
                                   7  8       0 
                                   5  4       0.6
                                   1  3       0 
                                   0  7       0
                                   6  6       0
                                   8  9       0.4", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try with `tidyverse`.  Convert the second dataset 'dat2' (with 2 rows in the OP's post) into 'long' format by splitting the 'lamps', 'vases' column (`separate_rows`), `left_join` with the first dataset ('df1' - labelled as 'df3' in OP's post), and with `replace_na` change the NA in 'est' to 0

```
library(tidyverse)
separate_rows(dat2, lamps, convert = TRUE) %>% 
    separate_rows(vases, convert = TRUE) %>% 
    left_join(dat1, ., by = c("lamps", "vases")) %>%
    replace_na(list(est = 0))
#   lamps vases est
#1     7     9 0.0
#2     1     6 0.0
#3     3     5 0.6
#4     7     8 0.0
#5     5     4 0.6
#6     1     3 0.0
#7     0     7 0.0
#8     6     6 0.0
#9     8     9 0.4
```